# Chef - Download Artifact from Nexus using remote_file resource

Tags: chef-infra, nexus, recipe

I'm using Chef to download a war file into a folder from nexus.The Recipe is as below

```
  remote_file '/home/Test/AAA.war' do    
  source 'https://IP.com:8082/ URL Of the Repo/AAA.war'    
  owner 'root'    
  group 'root'    
  mode '0755'   
  action :create  
  end
```

However If I run this recipe ,I am getting **Unauthorised access error**.

Is it necessary to give username and password for nexus login?

should i write a batch script to download from nexus instead of recipe?

Comment: Riotgames [artifact](https://github.com/RiotGamesCookbooks/artifact-cookbook) cookbook could be of help as inspiration (not maintained anymore as far as I know). Specially the download from nexus part [here](https://github.com/RiotGamesCookbooks/artifact-cookbook/blob/master/libraries/chef_artifact_nexus.rb) along with their nexus CLI gem [here](https://github.com/RiotGamesMinions/nexus_cli)

Answer (score 3):

First way I would verify if your Nexus server requires authentication to download any files.  I'd do this by opening your browser in Incognito Mode and go the URL of the `source` property of your `remote_file` resource.  I'm expecting it to give you a login page with a "Unauthorised access error".  This will be confirmation of your question that it is necessary to give a username and password for a Nexus login.

To do this, you can pass the necessary credentials to the Nexus server by using the `header` property of the `remote_file` resource.

Full details about this are available here. https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_file.html#properties

I don't know Nexus's login method specifically, but it could look something like this example from the docs page. `headers( "Authorization"=>"Basic #{ Base64.encode64("#{username}:#{password}").gsub("\n", "") }" )`

Comment: You can also just put it in the URL as per normal I think. `https://user:password@host/path`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it (based on **coderanger** answer).

```
nodejs_url = node['ci_cd']['ubu_nodejs_url']
...

remote_file nodejs_path do                                                                                          
  source   nodejs_url.gsub(/(https?:\/{2})/, '%s%s:%s@' % ['\1', artifactory_user, artifactory_pass])        
  checksum nodejs_url_checksum                                                                               
  owner    'root'                                                                                            
  group    'root'                                                                                            
  mode     '0644'                                                                                            
  notifies :install, 'dpkg_package[nodejs]', :immediately                                                    
  not_if   { ::File.exists?(nodejs_path) }                                                                            
end

dpkg_package 'nodejs' do                                                                                            
  source nodejs_path                                                                                               
  action :nothing                                                                                                  
end
```

In this example I created dependency between `remote_file` and `dpkg_package` just to manage guard (`not_if`) in one place.

Answer (score 0):

To download Nexus artifact on Windows Machine.. You can use the remote_file resource like this:

```
   remote_file  'D:/local/Chef/file.zip' do    
     source 'https://Nexus_URL_Address/file.zip'
     username = 'xxxx'
     password = 'xxxxxxx'
     headers( "Authorization"=>"Basic #{ Base64.encode64("#{username}:#{password}").gsub("\n", "") }" )
   end
```